# Hide Whatsapp profile picture from a certain user

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, whatsapp-messenger

I want to hide the profile picture in WhatsApp and still be able to message this person.

As far as I've understood, to message someone on WhatsApp, you need to store his/her number in the phonebook. Once you do this, you can't stop this person from seeing your picture, because WhatsApp does not have this options under the privacy settings.

Changing the "Who can view my profile picture" to nobody is not an option.

Also, if I delete the person from my phonebook, I will not be able to message his/her anymore. Same problem when using the app WhatsNot.

Is there a workaround or an app hide your profile pic from individual users?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way would be creating a group with just you & him, and then blocking him.. You'll not be able to message him directly, but only through that group (ofcourse he'll know you've blocked him)..

Another way would be starting a conversation between you & him and deleting his number (yes, it's mentioned in the question), but you'll still be able to chat with him (his number will be displayed instead of name) and make sure 'Who can see Profile Pic' is 'Contacts Only'..

Other than this, I don't think there's any other way..

Comment: There aren't any third party apps, that could do this, right? Also, is it possible to delete parts of a conversation or all text content, while keeping the conversation block in WhatsApp active?

Comment: No third party apps.. Yes, you can manually delete text messages & keep the conversation active, but make sure there's a minimum of 1 message..

Comment: If I added somebody beforehand in my contacts list, then started a conversation and then deleted this person from my contact list, will this person still be able to message me?

Comment: Yes, if a person has saved your number & if you're on WhatsApp, no matter what, he/she can text you (except if you've blocked that person).

Answer (score 0):

> I want to hide the profile picture in WhatsApp and still be able to
>   message this person.

**This is not possible.**

Looking at the official [FAQs](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/23741812) of `WhatsApp`, it is clearly mentioned that By default, WhatsApp will automatically set your privacy settings to allow any WhatsApp user to view your Read Receipts, last seen, **profile photo** and status.

> Your last seen, profile photo and/or status will be available **to all**
>   WhatsApp users.

But **If you [block a contact](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/general/21242423), that person will not see any updates to your profile picture.** 
In other words, Any changes made to your profile photo will no longer be visible to contacts you have blocked.

Also note that, When you block people on `WhatsApp`, you will no longer receive WhatsApp messages or calls from them.

So the best that you can do is to block the contact and that way that contact will not be able to see your profile photo and updates.

In order to Block a contact, you can follow the instructions mentioned in [this link.](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/21080506)

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to chat with other users without them seeing my profile pic. What I did was Account>Privacy>Profile Photo>My contacts. Then save their number and message them. After this simply delete their contact from your phone. This would prevent them from viewing your profile photo as they're not in your contacts. Note this is only viable for a few people unless you're incredibly good at recalling contacts for a lot of people without their names.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is not going to be a technical one and I'll probably get downvoted but I don't care. I think the problem is between the chair and the phone. You need to look at WHY you are trying to accomplish this. It sounds a bit strange that you would want or need to do this and maybe the problem can be solved with a proper discussion, or outright blocking. You can't have your cake and eat it. Decide whether this person has a place in your life. If they do then keep them and be honest with them. If they don't have a place in your life then block them and move on. Playing silly games will never achieve anything.

PS. Deleting a person from your phone contacts doesn't delete your previous conversations with that person. So you can delete a person from your contacts and still be able to message them, as long as you have messaged them previously. Then you just set  you privacy settings so only contacts can see your pic.

EDIT: I guess I caved in and went technical, but really, sort your friendships out.

Answer (score -1):

The valid way is root your Android phone, use a file explorer with root access, and in the whatsapp folder (only accessible when rooting) select the photo of the chosen contact, and give this file permissions with "only reading" (and NO writing permissions). This "freezes" the contact user photo avatar.

Comment: The question is asking about the user's profile picture, not the receiver's profile picture.